# Reading 8 byte binary string in chunks

Tags: python, binary, data-conversion

I have a binary python string that is encoded in 8 byte little endian.

```
byteString = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R@'
```

Now I want to decode it to regular doubles. It
should return 1 3 1 3 72 (in an array or single numbers, format does not matter for now).

When I use

```
struct.unpack('<d', byteString)
```

I only get an `unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes` error. Can anybody help me to see what I did wrong here?
`Struct.unpack()` works if I input exactly 8 bytes. However, how can I easily separate my string into 8 byte chunks?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to separate the data into 8 byte chunks in order to convert it. You can simply indicate a replication factor in front of the `d` type code for doubles in the format string — in this case `5`.

This is mentioned in the `struct` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters):

> A format character may be preceded by an integral repeat count. For example, the format string `'4h'` means exactly the same as `'hhhh'`.

Applied to your data:

```
import struct

byte_string = (b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00'
              b'\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R@')

format_string = '<5d'
floats = struct.unpack(format_string, byte_string)
print(floats)  # -> (1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 72.0)
```

If you wanted to split the string up into 8-byte chunks for some reason, you could do it by using string-slicing and a list-comprehension:

```
n = 8  # Chunk length
chunks = [byte_string[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(byte_string), n)]
for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R@'
```